# Is there a name for the function that returns a positionally-expanding version of its argument?

Tags: higher-order-functions, splat

Consider `splatter` in this Python code:

```
def splatter(fn):
    return lambda (args): fn(*args)

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
print map(splatter(add), zip(list1, list2))
```

Mapping an n-ary function over n zipped sequences seems like a common enough operation that there might be a name for this already, but I have no idea where I'd find that. It vaguely evokes currying, and it seems like there are probably other related argument-centric HOFs that I've never heard of. Does anyone know if this is a "well-known" function? When discussing it I am currently stuck with the type of awkward language used in the question title.

#### Edit

Wow, Python's `map` does this automatically. You can write:

```
map(add, list1, list2)
```

And it will do the right thing, saving you the trouble of `splatter`ing your function. The only difference is that `zip` returns a list whose length is the the length of its shortest argument, whereas `map` extends shorter lists with `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly saw this in my list of "Questions asked," and was surprised that I now know the answer.

There are two interpretations of the function that I asked.

The first was my intent: to take a function that takes a fixed number of arguments and convert it into a function that takes those arguments as a fixed-size list or tuple. In Haskell, the function that does this operation is called `uncurry`.

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

(Extra parens for clarity.)

It's easy to imagine extending this to functions of more than two arguments, though it can't be expressed in Haskell. But `uncurry3`, `uncurry4`, etc. would not be out of place.

So I was right that it "vaguely evokes currying," as it is really the opposite.

---

The second interpretation is to take a function that takes an intentionally variable number of arguments and return a function that takes a single list.

Because `splat` is so weird as a syntactic construct in Python, this is hard to reason about.

But if we imagine, say, JavaScript, which has a first-class named function for "splatting:"

```
varFn.apply(null, args)

var splatter = function(f) {
    return function(arg) {
        return f.apply(null, arg);
    };
};
```

Then we could rephrase that as merely a partial application of the "`apply`" function:

```
var splatter = function(f) {
    return Function.prototype.apply.bind(f, null);
};
```

Or using, [Underscore's `partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial), we can come up with the point-free definition:

```
var splatter = _.partial(Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.apply), _, null)
```

Yes, that is a nightmare.

(The alternative to `_.partial` requires defining some sort of `swap` helper and would come out even less readable, I think.)

So I think that the name of this operation is just "a partial application of `apply`", or in the Python case it's almost like a [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) of the splat operator -- if splat were an "actual" operator.

---

But the particular combination of `uncurry`, `zip`, and `map` in the original question is exactly `zipWith`, [as chris pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15332477/223274). In fact, [HLint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) by default [includes a rule](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/7eb61bab6f129d90680e4cf59701b9f856ce38bf/data/Default.hs#L137) to replace this complex construct with a single call to `zipWith`.

---

I hope that clears things up, past Ian.

Answer (score 1):

I think `zipWith` is the function that you are searching (this name is at least used in Haskell). It is even a bit more general. In Haskell `zipWith` is defined as follows (where the first line is just the type):

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWith f as bs
zipWith _ _      _      = []
```

And your example would be something like

```
zipWith (+) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
```

Since I do not know python very well I can only point to "[zipWith analogue in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766608/zipwith-analogue-in-python)".