# Python map on not equal length lists

Tags: python

In lisp I used to do things like that, knowing it won't crash:

```
 [3]> (mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3) '(1 2))
(2 4)
```

The equivalent in python seems to crash:

```
>>> map(lambda x,y : x + y, [1,2,3], [1,2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Is there a function in python that works like the lisp version on not-equal length lists? Or, is there a way to change the behavior of map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is suitable for Python 2.x (thanks to @user2357112). The documentation for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python 3.x says:

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

So, in Python 3.x you could just use `map`:

```
In [1]: list(map(lambda a, b: a + b, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]))
Out[1]: [2, 4]
```

---

But the documentation for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in Python 2.x says:

> If one iterable is shorter than another it is assumed to be extended
>   with None items.

So, you should firstly [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) these lists:

```
In [2]: map(sum, zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2]))
Out[2]: [2, 4]
```

Because `zip` will truncate returned list to the length of the shortest argument sequence (as said in documentation)

You could also define your own function `zip_with` ([example from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355166/1532460)):

```
import itertools

def zip_with(f, *coll):
    return itertools.starmap(f, itertools.izip(*coll))
```

Example of usage:

```
In [3]: list(zip_with(operator.add, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]))
Out[3]: [2, 4]
```

Comment: Note that the argument unpacking in `lambda (x, y): x + y` doesn't work in Python 3. [It messed with introspection and wasn't used much.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) That makes the transformation a bit messier in Python 3. Fortunately, Python 3's `map` already does what you want.

Comment: The documentation you're linking is for the Python 3 version of `map`, where none of this is necessary.